# What is the use of the ant duplicate attribute

Tags: ant, wsdl

In Ant1.8, I have a task like this :

```
 <jar destfile="@{destfile}.jar"
      duplicate="fail"
      manifest="@{srcfolder}/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF">       
    <fileset dir="${build_folder}/" excludes="${test_package}/**"/>
    <fileset dir="@{srcfolder}"  includes="**/*.xml" />
    <fileset dir="@{srcfolder}"  includes="**/*.properties" />
    <fileset dir="@{srcfolder}"  includes="**/*.wsdl" />
    <manifest>
       <attribute name="@{manifest-title}" value="@{manifest-name}"/>
    </manifest>
 </jar>
```

What is the duplicate="fail" supposed to do? I keep getting error like this:

```
Duplicate file META-INF/wsdl/someWsdl.wsdl was found and the duplicate attribute is 'fail'.
```

The wsdl is supposed to be there because just before building the jar i do wsimport and compile the generated classes.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/jar.html) has a section explaining the reasons behind the duplicate attribute:

> Please note that the zip format allows multiple files of the same fully-qualified name to exist within a single archive. This has been documented as causing various problems for unsuspecting users. If you wish to avoid this behavior you must set the duplicate attribute to a value other than its default, "add".

Are you sure you don't have more than one copy of the file "someWsdl.wsdl"?